# Does nextPageToken expire for Cloud Storage API?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm writing a program that iterates over all elements in the Google Cloud Storage project (first buckets and then objects within them), downloads them and perform certain operation on them. I'm wondering how I should write it so acquiring the list of buckets and objects will not cause any problems if the processing time of the items in a single page gets larger (up to minutes or hours). What I'm afraid of is that the nextPageToken expires in the meantime and subsequent call either returns the error or it will skip some elements.

According to the documentation of the [Bucket list endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list) the nextPageToken is simply the name of the last bucket in the returned list. So it seems like this token will never expire and I can keep it for later. Not fully sure what if the last bucket gets deleted in the meantime. Will that still work?

The situation gets more complicated for objects as the documentation of the [Object list endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) does not say anything on what that token represents nor is it safe to make long pause in between fetching subsequent pages of the list.

So far I found some contradicting information in the Internet about tokens in Google API (not necessarily Cloud Storage). Most of them were based on some experiments, while ideally I would like to find any official statement on that.

A safe approach would be to get list of all items to process upfront and save it locally and then iterate of that list to get particular objects. The downside of this is that for very large buckets the list of items could be very large and such list may require large amount of memory which might not be feasible for me.
The other approach is to make use of prefixes and simply iterate over a bucket as if it contains folders. This would work if in fact naming convention of the objects make use of it. If the list is flat and no prefixes are used I would have the same problem with the large list which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Here the magic revealed:

- Take your nextPageToken
- Decode it in base64
- And boom, you have the latest blob name returned in the current response.

So, no it doesn't expire. And yes, you can create manually your own next page token. If you process take hours, no worries, except if new file are added in the bucket in the meanwhile; at this moment, you can miss the new file added (if added before the next page token pointer)